# How to integrate both AngularJS & d3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm very new to D3.js and created a chart and bound the data to it via an API call.The problem is when I'm trying to integrate this page with the rest of my angular application, it is making indefinite API calls for data fetch. I have included all the D3 reference in Index.html page. I have also attached an Image of how it is making so many calls to API. Please suggest a solution and apologies if I'm doing some silly mistake.

This is the code to call the D3.js page upon clicking a button.

```
$scope.resourceAnalytics = function (event) {
        $window.open('/ResourceDetails', '_blank');
    }
```

Routing to that page in app.js

```
$routeProvider.when("/ResourceDetails", {
        templateUrl: '/Views/ResourceDetails.html',
    });
```

and Please find below the a sample of how I'm making the API call from the chart

```
<script>

                    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
                    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
                        width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
                        height = 260 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                    // parse the date / time
                    var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d-%b");
                    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b");

                    // set the ranges
                    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
                    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


                    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
                    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
                    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
                    var svg = d3.select("#linechart").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform",
                        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                    d3.json('http://localhost:51719/api/Admin/GetGenderDetails/', function (Jsondata) {
                        var data = Jsondata;

                        // format the data
                        data.forEach(function (d) {
                            d.GenderDate = formatTime(new Date(d.GenderDate));
                            //d.GenderDate = parseTime(d.GenderDate);
                            //d.Male = +d.Male;
                            //d.Female = +d.Female; // ConvertPercent
                        });
                        console.log(data)

                        // define the area
                        var area = d3.area()
                            .x(function (d) { return x(d.GenderDate); })
                            .y0(height)
                            .y1(function (d) { return y(d.Male); });


                        // define the area
                        var area2 = d3.area()
                            .x(function (d) { return x(d.GenderDate); })
                            .y0(height)
                            .y1(function (d) { return y(d.Female); });

                        // define the line
                        var valueline = d3.line()
                            .x(function (d) { return x(d.GenderDate); })
                            .y(function (d) { return y(d.Male); });

                        var valueline2 = d3.line()
                            .x(function (d) { return x(d.GenderDate); })
                            .y(function (d) { return y(d.Female); });


                        // scale the range of the data
                        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.GenderDate; }));
                        //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
                        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max(d.Male, d.Female); })]);

                        // add the area
                        svg.append("path")
                            .data([data])
                            .attr("class", "area")
                            .attr("d", area);

                        // add the valueline path.
                        svg.append("path")
                            .data([data])
                            .attr("class", "line")
                            .attr("d", valueline);

                        svg.append("path")
                            .data([data])
                            .attr("class", "area2")
                            .attr("d", area2);

                        // Add the valueline2 path.
                        svg.append("path")
                            .data([data])
                            .attr("class", "line")
                            .style("stroke", "#4DADDA")
                            .attr("d", valueline2);

                        // add the X Axis
                        svg.append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

                        // add the Y Axis
                        svg.append("g")
                            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
                    });
                </script>
```

[Multiple API calls made by D3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2pYg.png)

Comment: It would be hard to detect the problem without seeing the full code.

Comment: @shushan - I have added the d3.js code from which I'm calling the api. Please check now.